# Comment dit-on « I’ll tell you what » ?

Tags: expressions, traduction

Ça s’utilise quand on veut passer un accord ou dire les conditions de quelque chose.

Par exemple :

- I’ll tell you what. You can get one dip of ice cream. Alright? Just one dip.

ou :

- Tell you what. We’ll go on vacation next summer and you can think about what you’d like to do and we’ll try it. Sound good?

En plus, comment dirait-on « Sound good? » dans ce contexte ? Merci !

Comment: I've already heard people saying " tu me rappelles et tu me dis quoi" or " ok, je te dirai quoi" meaning " tu me rappelles et tu me dis ce qu'il en est ( de telle ou telle affaire)" , " ok, je te dirai ma réponse ( sur telle ou telle question)". But this ( rather incorrect) french expression does not qualify at all as a translation of the english expression you are referring to.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Pas sûr qu'il existe en français une locution qui rende compte des différents emplois de `tell you what`. J'ai l'impression qu'il y a ces trois nuances :

**Concession** :

- > *I’ll tell you what. You can get one dip of ice cream. Alright? Just one dip.*
  >
  > **Bon**, tu peux prendre une cuillérée de glace. Juste une, hein ?
- > *Tell you what, round it up to $10 and we call it a deal.*
  >
  > **Allez**, on arrondit à 10$ et c'est d'accord.

**Confession, confidence :**

- > *Tell you what. We’ll go on vacation next summer and you can think about what you’d like to do and we’ll try it. Sound good?*
  >
  > **Tu sais quoi** ? On va partir en vacances etc. (credits to @Ctouw)
- > *Tell you what, I've never liked him.*
  >
  > **Entre nous**, depuis le début il ne me plaît pas.
- > *Tell you what, yesterday's announcement was just a damp squib, you shouldn't worry about it.*
  >
  > **Je vais te dire**, la nouvelle d'hier n'était qu'une esbrouffe, n'y pense plus.

**Conclusion :**

- > *Tell you what, we'll ask Jane and she'll decide for us.*
  >
  > **Voilà ce qu'on va faire** : on va demander à Jane de décider pour nous.
- > *Tell you what, if they don't behave, we'll just have them wait outside.*
  >
  > **Écoute**, s'ils ne se tiennent pas, on n'aura qu'à les laisser dehors.

Comment: Très belle réponse. On pourra aussi penser à *«Écoute(-moi bien)»* pour une concession partielle d’un parent aux demandes incessantes d’un enfant.

Comment: Nice answer. You only miss a stronger "I know better than you" option:. Laisse-moi t'expliquer, tu peux avoir juste une boule de glace. It's almost rude, but sounds closer to the first example.

Comment: I think _voilà ce qu’on va faire_ is probably closest to the meaning that underlies all these usages (except “Tell you what, I’ve never liked him”, but that doesn’t sound very idiomatic to me – perhaps a dialectal usage?), namely that what follows is a suggestion of a compromise to somehow appease or satisfy the listener. It’s part of a negotiation somehow.

Answer (score 13):

Pour ma part, je dirais *Tu sais quoi ?*

- Tu sais quoi ? Tu peux avoir un petit bout de glace, d'accord ? Mais juste un petit bout.
- Tu sais quoi, on va partir en vacances l'été prochain. Tu pourras réfléchir à ce que tu aimerais faire et nous le ferrons. Ça te va ?

Pour répondre à la deuxième question, *Sounds good* se traduirait donc par *Ça te va ?* ou encore *Ça te convient ?* Ou encore, tout simplement : *OK ?*

Comment: D'accord avec *Ça te va*, j'utilise aussi souvent *Qu'est-ce (que) t'en penses ?*

Comment: "Tu sais quoi ?" is definitely the most natural thing that comes to mind.

Comment: _Tu sais quoi ?_ could be directly translated to _You know what?_

Comment: Définitivement la traduction qui respecte l'idée de la question demandée.

Answer (score 3):

To render the idea faithfully enough in French you have to use more words but they go somewhat beyond the basic notion ; the consecrated expression is "**Je vais [te/vous] dire [ce qu'on va faire/ce que je vais faire] ;**" (*as well:* "ce que nous allons faire") but it doesn't always correspond to the context ; it can be used only in the second sentence; in some sentences  a change of "you can" into "I permit you" does the trick; however, for plain permissions that form carries too much importance and something else is necessary (case of the first sentence).

**I**

In the first sentence, the decision taken, which is hinted in "I tell you what" can be replaced by the basic modality along which the decision has been taken ;

- I’ll tell you what. You can get one dip of ice cream. Alright? Just one dip.
  *Passons pour cette fois. Tu peux prendre une louche de crème glacée … Tu es content ? Mais pas plus.*

Other options: Ça va pour cette fois !
 Écoute ! (Harrap dictionary),  Bon! Écoute !, Alors écoute …

An example where the permission involves more responsability and where the modification is possible;

- I tell you what. You can use that short cut through my property from now but I hold you responsible for any damage caused to the vegetation along the path, in particular the trees, and if any one of them is maimed in any way the path will be closed to you forever.
  *Je vais vous dire ce que je vais faire; je vais vous permettre, de ce jour, l'utilisation du raccourci à travers ma propriété mais je vous tiens pour responsable de toute dégradation à la végétation environnante, en particulier les arbres, et si l'un d'eux est mutilé d'une  quelconque façon le chemin vous sera interdit pour toujours.*

**II**

- Tell you what. We’ll go on vacation next summer and you can think about what you’d like to do and we’ll try it. Sounds good?
  *Je vais te dire ce qu'on va faire ; on va partir en vacance cet été et tu peux déjà penser à ce que tu aimerais et ce que tu aura décidé on fera. Comment ça te va ?*

Besides the possibilities in this [answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/36491/17649) (Ça te va ?, Ça te convient ?, OK ?) the following are of some interest;

- Qu'est-ce que tu/vous en dis/dites ? — Qu'est-ce que ça te/vous dit ? — Ça te/vous dit ? (informal) — Comment ça (te/vous) va ? — Est-ce que ça (te/vous) va ?

Comment: L'idée que ça puisse être remplacé par _the basic modality_ est une piste intéressante...

Answer (score 0):

> Tu peux avoir une portion de crème glacée mais une seule, d'accord ?
>   Je dis bien une seule/J'ai bien dit une seule.
>
> On pourrait partir en vacances l'été prochain et tu pourrais penser
>   aux choses que tu voudrais faire et on essayera de les faire. Est-ce
>   que ça te convient/Qu'est-ce que tu en penses ?
>
> Si on partait en vacances l'été prochain et que tu pensais aux
>   activités que tu voulais faire et qu'on essayait de les réaliser...
>   Est-ce que ça te conviendrait ?

Selon la source il s'agit [soit](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/tell%20you%20what) *d'introduire une suggestion ou d'insister sur une affirmation*, [soit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tell_you_what) *de présenter un compromis ou un arrangement où l'interlocuteur retire un bénéfice quelconque* ; le tout en langage courant. C'est comme un introducteur associé à une forme de ponctuation comme le deux-points (:) dans une négociation ou un échange avec un interlocuteur. Je ne vois pas pourquoi on tenterait d'émuler syntaxiquement la position de l'expression *I'll tell you what* dans la phrase pour présenter une condition, aménager un compromis ou faire valoir un bénéfice, ni même pour insister sur ce qu'on dit.

On n'a qu'à employer la répétition des éléments importants (affirmation + *je dis/j'ai dit*, suivi des éléments), l'adverbe (*je dis bien*), voire antéposé (*Honnêtement...* etc. ; dans certains scénarios on pourrait même antéposer un pronom tonique, *moi, je dis...*), à insister sur un élément (*une seule*), à utiliser le verbe au conditionnel (*on pourrait*) ou l'hypothèse directement (*si*). On peut aussi employer d'autres tours comme l'impératif à la première personne du pluriel du verbe [*dire*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dire) (*disons*) pour *convenir*, ou employer le [*si*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/si) « avec *nous* ou *on*, associant le demandeur et son interlocuteur, créant une connivence » avec l'imparfait créant une « éventualité dépendant de la volonté de l'interlocuteur » (TLFi). Si on veut faire une suggestion on n'a qu'à la faire : « Voici ma suggestion : », « je suggère/propose que/de... ».

---

En résumé à mon avis la meilleure manière de traduire *I'll tell you what* est essentiellement de l'omettre et de se concentrer sur les verbes, leurs temps et leurs modes, l'adverbe et la structure des propositions de la phrase.